# Not able to run Emulator using the Android studio for my Flutter app, getting NO CONNECTED DEVICES error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Please Note: I tried several available solutions but none worked for me since yesterday hence posting this. I have also mentioned below what are things I have tried so far.

I am new to Android Studio and Flutter application and I am trying to build a simple Flutter app using the Android Studio.

1. I have downloaded and kept my flutter files in `C:\src\flutter`. Also added to Environment variables.
2. I have installed the Android Studio and also installed the Flutter plugin with the Dart.
3. I created the `Virtual Emulator Device` using the `Tools->AVD Manager` and choose the `Nexus 6` with the `Android 8.1`
4. Created a simple project using the `File->New Flutter Project->Flutter Application`.
5. When I try to run this application I get the following error:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot it shows that the `No Devices` in the emulator section not sure how to run it.

Things I have tried so far:

1. If I run `flutter doctor` then I get a tick for all the things except `Connect Devices`. My guess is that it is obvious because I have not connected any external device but using the emulators.

[image]

2. I tried to create the emulators using the command `flutter emulators --create Nexus_6` and tried to launch it using the command `flutter emulator launch`.
3. I tried running the Android studio as an `Administrator`.
4. Restarted the system several times.
5. My `adb.exe` was crashing so updated the windows and replaced it with the new adb.exe as mentioned in one of the solutions.
6. My `flutter emulators` show following list in the command prompt:
   [image]
7. I tried checking the folder in `Appdata -> Local` seems to be fine as per other mentioned answers.
8. When I run the `Emulator` using the `AVD Manager` from Android Studio I see that it is firing up the `Android Emulator` but it is not responding. In addition to this, I also observe in my task manager that process `adb.exe(32 bit)` is running whereas my `WINDOW 8.1 is 64 bit`. Is this expected?

I am not sure If I missed something here. Please help me on how to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you try another IDE such as Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Actually I would like to do in Android Studio as I am following one of the tutorial where they are using the Android Studio. Isnt it possible to run in Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I just wanted to see if it's just an IDE error or system

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not have the Visual Studio in my system. I need to install it freshly. If possible could you please provide some suggestions for the Android Studio? Shall I uninstall and install it again?

Comment: Uninstalling Android Studio is a royal pain as you would have to install all of the SDKs. I'll try and find some stuff, do you have an antivirus installed?

Comment: Nope, I do not have any antivirus installed in my Windows 8.1 machine. Also, I have updated my windows yesterday.

Comment: If it was working fine before, I would re-install Android Studio.

Comment: No This is my first application using the Android Studio. It is not working since I began working on it. The same issue persist until now.

Comment: @BATMAN have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using below command on Flutter worked for me:

```
flutter config --android-sdk [android-sdk-path]
```

The path is usually C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
this path can be found from android studio - SDK manager also.